# "Warning:mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in?"And after searching I rectified my code as below

Tags: php, mysql

DisplayLandlord PHP:
    I couldn't get the output.The query is not fetching the result

```
 <?php include("dbconfig.php"); ?>
    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM rmuruge4_landlord"; 
    $result = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect(),$query);
    if ($result === false) 
    {die(mysqli_error(mysqli_connect())); }
    echo "<div class='bs-example'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-striped'>"; 
    echo "<tr><th>LLID</th><th>LName</th><th>Phone</th><th>Address</th></td>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['LLID'] . "</td><td >" . $row['LName'] . "</td><td >". $row['Phone'] . "</td><td >" . $row['Address'] . "</td></tr>"; }
    echo "</table>"; 
    echo "</div>";
    mysqli_close(mysqli_connect()); 
    ?>

dbconfig.php:
Connection is successful
```

Comment: Do you have a question or are you only reporting your success? ;-)

Comment: I think problem is with your `mysqli_connect()` Post code of your `dbconfig.php` file

Comment: umm... why are you doing [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) with no params in `$result = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect(),$query);`?

Comment: You not to declare what you want it to do IF your query fails!

Answer (score 0):

A bit in "wild-guessing mode", but ....

```
<?php
require 'dbconfig.php';
// let's assume dbconfig.php provides DB_HOST, DB_USER, ...
// there's something to be said about defining DB_PASS  ...but anyway, that's worth another question

// establish the connection/create connection instance
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DBNAME);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    trigger_error( sprintf('mysqli connect error (%d) %s', $mysqli->connect_errno, $mysqli->connect_error), E_USER_ERROR);
    die;
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM rmuruge4_landlord';
// use _that_ connection resource to send/retrieve data to/from the MySQL server
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli ,$query); 
if ($result === false)  {
    // by default you shouldn't send the exact, detailed error message to the client
    // see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leakage
    // die(mysqli_error(mysqli_connect()));
    someErrorHandler( mysqli_error($mysql) );
}
else {
    // php supports multi-line string literals
    echo '
        <div class="bs-example">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr><th>LLID</th><th>LName</th><th>Phone</th><th>Address</th></tr>
    ';
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    // echo can take more than one parameter, no need to use string-concatenation here.
    echo
        '<tr><td>',
          // just like you have to ensure the proper encoding when putting literal string values into sql statements
          // you have to use something like htmlspecialchars() here to prevent, e.g. the value in Address to break your html structure
            htmlspecialchars($row['LLID']),
        '</td><td >',
            htmlspecialchars($row['LName']),
        '</td><td >',
            htmlspecialchars($row['Phone']),
        '</td><td >',
            htmlspecialchars($row['Address'])
        '</td></tr>'
    ;
   }
    echo '
            </table>
        </div>';
```